# Determining window focus in mode-line?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a proper predicate for determining whether the window has focus in the mode line? I'm trying to do some things in my mode line that require more flexibility than just using `mode-line-inactive`.

I've been doing:

```lisp
(defun window-has-focus-p ()
  "When called in eval sexp in mode or header line template,
returns true if this is the active window."
  (eq
   (frame-selected-window)
   (get-buffer-window)))
```

And it worked very well on two of my computers for months (Windows 7 and Debian). However, I tried using it on another Debian box yesterday and it reported `t` in every mode line for every window... totally broken.

I haven't been able to find a standard predicate call for this purpose, and I can't figure out why this hacked-up one seems to work on some devices and not others. Additionally, I did evaluate `(force-mode-line-update t)` with <kbd>M-:</kbd> and that did not help.

Emacs version is 24.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the mode-line-format is evaluated for a given window, this window is temporarily made the `selected-window`.  In Emacs<=24.3 this was made only halfway: `selected-window` was changed, but not `frame-selected-window`.  This meant that temporarily `(frame-selected-window)` was not equal to `(selected-window)` and breaking this (normally) invariant was a source of various corner case bugs.  So we fixed it in 24.4, which means that your code broke.

To make it work in 24.4, you need to save the "selected-window" as seen by the user before the mode-line-format is processed.
You can do that with

```
(defvar my-real-selected-window nil)
(add-function :before pre-redisplay-function
              (lambda (_wins) (setq my-real-selected-window (selected-window))))
```

So you can then use `my-real-selected-window` in your `mode-line-format` to know which window is the one that should be highlighted specially.

Comment: emacs --version reports "GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1", and the proposed fix (perhaps expectedly) does not work..

Comment: Sorry for the comment spam, I didn't realize SO didn't allow editing comments. But the reason it doesn't work seems to be that my-real-selected-window is nil...it looks like the advice isn't ever run...

Comment: 24.3.50 is old and shouldn't be used any more.  As for your problem, indeed I forgot to put the (unused) arg in my function (it's fixed now).

Comment: That worked, switching accepted answer as this appears to be less of a hack.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using this in my configuration

```
;;; active modeline detection hack
(add-hook 'post-command-hook
          (lambda ()
            (when (not (minibuffer-selected-window))
              (setq powerline-selected-window (selected-window)))))
```

Maybe the `post-command-hook` is not the most elegant solution, but is working correctly for me.

Comment: It's a shame there's no better way to do this, but this does work on the machine where my hack didn't.